# XmlReader/Writer gives errors with end elements

Tags: c#, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I have a stream which represents a wellformed xml document. I'm experimenting with XmlReader/Writer and I was just trying to read the entire stream and write it out again.

This seems to work fine for normal end elements:

```
<Context>some text</Context>
```

and for "short" end elements like this:

```
<Context/>
```

In those cases I correctly get a start and end element event.

However, if a short end element is followed immediately by a normal end element:

```
<Item><Context/></Item>
```

Then I do get a start element on the context element, but NOT an end element!

What is wrong with this simple switch of reading and than writing that explains this weird behaviour?

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(GetTestXMLStream())))
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, new XmlWriterSettings {Indent = 4}))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
            {
                //Triggers for <Context/>
                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                break;
            }
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
            {
                writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                break;
            }
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
            {
                //Triggers for <Context/>, but not if <Context/> is followed by </Item>. But does trigger for </Item> itself.
                writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty elements are not followed by `EndElement`. So you need to check for [IsEmptyElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodereader.isemptyelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to process such nodes (partial sample from article):

```
   while (reader.Read()){
     if (reader.IsStartElement()){
       if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
          Console.WriteLine("<{0}/>", reader.Name);
       else{
```

Note that using `XElement` (possibly with LINQ-to-XML) or even `XmlDocument` APIs are generally easier to work with and have more samples. Consider switching unless you XML documents are 10Mb+.